# Cannot get VLCJ JavaFX running on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: java, javafx, vlcj

I downloaded the VLCJ JavaFX example so that I was sure that the problem wasn't related to my code, but I still can't make it run on Ubuntu, only on Windows 10. I get this strange error that creates this "hr_err_pidxxxx.log"

I'm using openjdk-15 and Ubuntu 20.10 with minimal installation, but I've installed the full vlc, thought `sudo apt install vlc` and ffmepg (not sure if needed), so that all necessary native libraries were loaded.

It's worth mentioning that I had to change the pom.xml dependency of vlcj to 4.7.0, since 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT it's not available on Maven Repo.

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f03288ebfbf, pid=8056, tid=8133
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (15.0.2+7) (build 15.0.2+7-27)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libswscale.so.5+0x69fbf]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/guilherme/Downloads/vlcj-javafx-demo-master/core.8056)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/guilherme/Downloads/vlcj-javafx-demo-master/hs_err_pid8056.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Some highlights of the log hs_err_pidxxxx.log generated:

```
---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: BlingMonitor.jar

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz, 5 cores, 7G, Ubuntu 20.10
Time: Sun Feb 28 23:56:47 2021 -03 elapsed time: 25 seconds (0d 0h 0m 25s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread is native thread

Stack: [0x00007fb5cf039000,0x00007fb5cf138000],  sp=0x00007fb5cf1346a8,  free space=1005k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libadjust_plugin.so+0x5e30]


siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00000280000001e4

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb6b6f811ec]


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 
[error occurred during error reporting (inspecting top of stack), id 0xb, SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb6b6f811ec]


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap address: 0x0000000083a00000, size: 1990 MB, Compressed Oops mode: 32-bit
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000800b18000

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 131072K, used 69449K [0x0000000083a00000, 0x0000000100000000)
  region size 1024K, 28 young (28672K), 7 survivors (7168K)
 Metaspace       used 21519K, capacity 22498K, committed 22832K, reserved 1069056K
  class space    used 3000K, capacity 3384K, committed 3456K, reserved 1048576K
Heap Regions: E=young(eden), S=young(survivor), O=old, HS=humongous(starts), HC=humongous(continues), CS=collection set, F=free, OA=open archive, CA=closed archive, TAMS=top-at-mark-start (previous, next)
```

Also I get thousands of lines of all "lib(something).so", like:

```
7fb5fe304000-7fb5fe305000 r--p 00008000 08:03 924774                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7.3.1

7fb5fe327000-7fb5fe328000 r--p 00007000 08:03 925369                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisfile.so.3.3.8

7fb5e5a82000-7fb5e5a83000 rw-p 0000a000 08:03 1053204                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/demux/libes_plugin.so

7fb5e5a64000-7fb5e5a65000 r--p 00005000 08:03 1053235                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/demux/libwav_plugin.so

7fb6303a2000-7fb6303a4000 r--p 00043000 08:03 924380                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.12.0
```

And so on.

Comment: What is the version of VLC? Is your VLC definitely 64-bit? Unfortunately these errors can be very hard to troubleshoot, the bare minimum you must do is make sure all your versions of everything are compatible. Using vlcj 4.7.0 like you've done should be fine. Although you mentioning vlcj 5.0.0-SNAPSHOT is a bit of a red flag since that requires a completely different (unreleased) version of VLC.

Comment: The version of my VLC it's 3.0.11.1 Vetinari and it' s says "amd64-035.buildd Sep 22 2020" so I'm pretty sure that's 64 bit. I've installed Ubuntu on minimum preset, so I don't know if maybe it's something missing, like a library or some software, can you list the dependencies to run VLCJ properly? I look at the official VLCJ website but it only indicates the VLC itself

Comment: And JavaFX version? You're trying to run the *unchanged* vlcj-javafx-demo project, from the master branch? And you're running from inside an IDE or standalone? vlcj only needs its own Maven dependencies and LibVLC, nothing else.

Comment: Also, look inside that hotspot log and maybe edit your post to include anything that looks relevant, like stack-traces, but don't post the whole thing.

Comment: missing `libvlc-dev`?

Comment: I'm using JavaFX 15, but I have a strong feeling that it's related to something missing. I tried the ```libvlc-dev``` but unfortunaly was not the case. I've tried Ubuntu 20.10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on virtual machines, and worked well on 20.04, installing VLC and openjdk-14 right after updating all the system on the first boot.

Comment: I can duplicate this error using JDK 11 and 16 on Ubuntu 20.10. On CentOS 8 and Rocky Linux 8, everything works fine, so it seems to be somewhat specific to Ubuntu. The error appears to be in libswscale.so (an ffmpeg library) that's involved in pixel format conversion. https://www.ffmpeg.org/libswscale.html